# How to install a golang package in a docker file?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I'm new in docker and I want to setting-up a docker-compose for my django app. in the backend of my app, I have golang packages too and run that in djang with subprocess library.
But, when I want to install a package using `go install github.com/x/y@latest` and then copy its binary to the project directory, it gives me the error: `package github.com/x/y@latest: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode`
I searched a lot in the internet but didn't find a solution to solve my problem. Could you please tell me where I'm wrong?

here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.18.1-bullseye as go-build
       
# Install go package
RUN go install github.com/hakluke/hakrawler@latest \
 && cp $GOPATH/bin/hakrawler /usr/local/bin/
 
# Install main image for backend
FROM python:3.8.11-bullseye

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install Dist packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common libpq5 python3-dev musl-dev git netcat-traditional golang \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/redteam_toolkit/

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project, and then the go package
COPY . .
COPY --from=go-build /usr/local/bin/hakrawler /usr/src/redteam_toolkit/toolkit/scripts/webapp/
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:4334
    container_name: toolkit_webapp
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/redteam_toolkit/
    ports:
      - 4334:4334
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13.4-bullseye
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=redteam_toolkit_db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

the `get.py` file inside `/usr/src/redteam_toolkit/toolkit/scripts/webapp/` directory, to just run the go package, and list files in this dir:

```
import os
import subprocess

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print(f"Current path is: {BASE_DIR}")

def go(target_url):
    run_go_package = subprocess.getoutput(
        f"echo {target_url} | {BASE_DIR}/webapp/hakrawler -t 15 -u"
    )
    list_files = subprocess.getoutput(f"ls {BASE_DIR}/webapp/")
    
    print(run_go_package)
    print(list_files)

go("https://example.org")
```

and then I just run:

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build

$ docker-compose exec webapp python toolkit/scripts/webapp/get.py
```

The output is:

```
Current path is: /usr/src/redteam_toolkit/toolkit/scripts
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/src/redteam_toolkit/toolkit/scripts/webap/hakrawler: not found
__init__.py
__pycache__
scr.py
gather.py
```

Comment: Could you also show the error message? Also please take a look at [How to a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @tbhaxor I posted the error in the line 5.

Comment: Instead of `go install github.com/x/y@latest` try `go install github.com/x/y` @danial

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi I tried, it gaves: `Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/x/@v/list": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: In the `apt-get -y install` line add package `ca-certificates` and run the `go install github.com/x/y` after that @danial

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi Thanks. It gaves me the error: `cannot find module providing package github.com/hakluke/hakrawler: invalid github.com/ import path "github.com/hakluke"`

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the go package build itself and not the docker build. If you can provide more info about what you are installing and what you are planning to do, that will be helpful

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi I installed that go package on my machine without problem. here is the link: `github.com/hakluke/hakrawler` . what scenario I can do with this repository instead of `go install ...`?

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: @m0j0 go1.15.15

Comment: Try adding this to your Dockerfile: `GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/hakluke/hakrawler` You might also need to add `$HOME/go/bin` to your path:  `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a really good candidate for a multi-stage build:

```
FROM golang:1.18.0 as go-build
       
# Install packages
RUN go install github.com/x/y@latest \
 && cp $GOPATH/bin/pacakge /usr/local/bin/
 
FROM python:3.8.11-bullseye as release
...
COPY --from=go-build /usr/local/bin/package /usr/src/toolkit/toolkit/scripts/webapp/
...
```

Your compose file also needs to be updated, it is masking the entire `/usr/src/redteam_toolkit` folder with the volume mount. Delete that volume mount to see the content of the image.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I tried that, the package had been installed and image created, but while testing that package in webapp, I got this message: `['/bin/sh: 1: /usr/src/toolkit/toolkit/scripts/webapp/package: not found'] `. it seems it didn't copied.

Comment: @danial the above specifically picked two Debian images for both Go and your runtime. Did you mix Alpine and Debian? Does the binary exist in the image? Check for other dynamic links with `ldd /usr/src/toolkit/toolkit/scripts/webapp/package` in the container.

Comment: No, both are debian based. (speceficly bullseye). Does that related to "context" in my dockr-compose.yml file too? because of accessing to other directory. I just ran a "ls" command in the destination directory, the file didn't exists there.

Comment: @danial at this point it's just a series of guesses since I can't see your inputs, commands being run, or their outputs. I'd recommend updating the question with a [mcve] so we can reproduce the errors and provide a working solution.

Comment: Sure, I just updated my question, does the information regarded to the problem is enough?

Comment: @danial Your compose file mounts a volume at `.:/usr/src/redteam_toolkit/`. You won't see any files from the image when you do that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new in docker. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: @danial Delete the volume from your compose yml or store the binary in a different location in your image.

Comment: Thanks for the help. the problem has been solved by deleting specified volumes.

Answer (score 0):

`GOPATH` mode does not work with Golang modules, in your Dockerfile file, add:
`RUN unset GOPATH`

Answer (score -1):

use `RUN go get <package_repository>`